# How does a TPL Parallel.for handle data locking

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to understand the more lower level operations of the TPL and was wondering how a parallel for handles data locking, e.g. Performing a calculations over a 2D array. I ve been going around in circles on MSDN and haven't been able to find a detailed explanation.  Any suggestions?

Comment: IME, TPL does not handle this at all.  There are various limitations around threading helpers.  File locking is one of them.  "Automatic concurrency" if you will, is limited to in memory issues.  Windows Workflow Foundation suffers from similar problems.  Sometimes old school multithreading is the way to go (waithandles and such).

Comment: TPL is not a "threading helper" nor is Workflow Foundation appropriate or even used for fine-grained concurrency. In fact, PLINQ and TPL implement different concurrency paradigms (task concurrency vs data concurrency). Threads are just the way used to process the tasks/data. A TaskScheduler could use fibers, external processes or remote machines to execute its payload and it wouldn't be visible to the task itself or the lambdas

Answer (score 1):

If you access/modify shared mutable state in the body of the for loop, synchronizing that access is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need any locking because there is never any situation in which multiple threads are accessing the same locations in memory.  There is a single thread that is scheduling work for the workers, cutting out sections of the work to be done and giving them out.  Because there is only one thread doing this, it doesn't need to synchronize with anyone else.  None of the workers (should be) working on shared data.

Comment: That really depends on what kind of code is inside loop. You certainly can write code using `Parallel.For()` that requires locking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a gross oversimplification to paint the picture in code; post this into a console app and it'll spit out the data and which thread is working on it. You can update this to work with your own data to make it more relevant.

```
        var list = new List<int>(64);

        for (var i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        var result = Parallel.ForEach(list, entry =>
        {
            var line = string.Format("Thread ID {0} is listing entry {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, entry);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        });

        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?